# Blackberry 10: Is there any garbage collector or system clean method in QT

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10

I have created an application which works in background as I got SMS it will show a toast message. But After 7-8 times it wont show any toast message for new incoming or outgoing message. At that time if I open my app by clicking icon it will works again and again shows toast messages for new incoming message.

So, I think may be in background process it will create a hanging condition after some frequent events. Can anybody suggest me that, is there any garbage collection or System clean or memory free option is present in BB 10 programming.

Plz help me. Thanks in advance. If required I will share my code.

Comment: If you are programming natively, using C++ and Cascades/Qt, then no there is no garbage collection. You have to allocated and deallocate memory according to your programs needs. Cascades/Qt provides some help for this, but it is not automatic.

Comment: Thanks @Richard it solved now. I delete or reset variables value to null. Now my app is not hanging any more

Answer (score 1):

The closest you get to garbage collection is that if you delete a parent object, the children get deleted as well. That's often enough to manage your UI (you delete a screen, and all the components go with it), but there are lots of times you will need to manually delete objects.